# Why is AndAlso statement far slower than a nested If condition?

Tags: vb.net

I was optimizing and otherwise streamlining a little piece of code when I discovered that

```
Public Shared Function confirm_byte_sequence(needle As Byte(), haystack As Byte(), pos As Integer)
    For i = 1 To needle.Length - 1
        If needle(i) <> haystack(i + pos) Then Return False
    Next
    Return True
End Function

Public Shared Function find_byte_sequence(needle As Byte(), haystack As Byte(), start As Integer)
    Dim first = needle(0)
    For i = start To haystack.Length - needle.Length
        If haystack(i) = first AndAlso confirm_byte_sequence(needle, haystack, i) Then Return i
    Next
    Return -1
End Function
```

is almost 4 times slower than

```
Public Shared Function confirm_byte_sequence(needle As Byte(), haystack As Byte(), pos As Integer)
    For i = 1 To needle.Length - 1
        If needle(i) <> haystack(i + pos) Then Return False
    Next
    Return True
End Function

Public Shared Function find_byte_sequence(needle As Byte(), haystack As Byte(), start As Integer)
    Dim first = needle(0)
    For i = start To haystack.Length - needle.Length
        If haystack(i) = first Then
            If confirm_byte_sequence(needle, haystack, i) Then Return i
        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function
```

AFAIK these 2 should be functionally identical, whats going on?

Comment: How you are benchmarking both implementations?

Comment: If you want to know why a certain piece of code behaves a certain way, look at the IL code generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that I used for testing and was never able to see even a 10% difference between the two:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim watch As Stopwatch
    Dim a = True
    Dim b = True
    Dim c = True

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

    For i = 0 To 10000000000
        If a AndAlso b Then
            c = Not c
        End If

        'a = Not a
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed)

    a = True
    c = True
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

    For i = 0 To 10000000000
        If a Then
            If b Then
                c = Not c
            End If
        End If

        'a = Not a
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

I tried different combinations of `True` and `False` for `a` and `b` and I included the toggling of `a` sometimes and not others.  Execution times were in the approximate range of 16-20 seconds and the two times never differed by much.